# Getting the X,Y coordinates or POSITION of a slider-handle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The question is straightforward:
How do I get the POSITION of a slider-handle since it is contained inside a slider?

Can I use the [getBoundingClient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11396681/6143482) also?

Do you use this to call the slider-handle?

```
.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb
```

or

```
.slider::-moz-range-thumb
```

I want to do something like this:

```
var mySliderHandleCursor = document.getElementById('THE_ID_OF_MY_SLIDER_CURSOR');
mySliderHandleCursor.getXposition();
mySliderHandleCursor.getYposition();
```

I'm asking this because I want to place the highlighted image below the position of my slider-cursor, as illustrated:
[image]

**So my plan is to:**

```
1. Get X of slider-cursor assign it to marker-image
2. Get Y of slider-cursor and assign it to marker-image +20px
```

Comment: May we see a  [mcve] - for now we do not even know if your slider is a jQuery plugin, a jQuery UI thing or an HTML5 slider - at least show some HTML

Comment: Question is no clear. Add more info, or draw a schematic picture with your coordinates. May be you are searching for scrollX, or may be you are searching for offsetX

Comment: Certainly looks like this could be used: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46448994/get-the-offset-position-of-an-html5-range-slider-handle